# how to stop sinatra from running?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

If `ruby myapp.rb` starts sinatra previewing at localhost:4567, how can I programatically stop/halt/kill it? Terminal command (other than Ctrl-C), or Rake tasks would be fine.

I need to incorporate this into a Rake task or terminal.

Comment: sinatra *never* runs. Her boots are made for *walking...*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In myapp.rb, add this before sinatra starts:

```
puts "This is process #{Process.pid}"
```

When you want to kill it, do this in a shell:

```
kill <pid>
```

Where `<pid>` is the number outputted by myapp.rb. If you want to do it in ruby:

```
Process.kill 'TERM', <pid>
```

Both of these will let sinatra run it's exit routine. If you don't want to type in the pid every time, have myapp.rb open a file and put it's pid in it. Then when you want to stop it, read the file and use that. Example:

```
# myapp.rb:
File.open('myapp.pid', 'w') {|f| f.write Process.pid }

# shell:
kill `cat myapp.pid`

# ruby:
Process.kill 'TERM', File.read('myapp.pid')
```

Comment: Thanks, expecially for the last code - which I'm using. I needed to convert to int for `Process.kill 'TERM', File.read('myapp.pid').to_i`

Answer (score 14):

In OS X, from the command line (Terminal.app, or DTerm) just enter:

```
$ killall ruby
```

every ruby process will stop. Sinatra too.

In Linux (and other UNIXes), you can:

```
$ ps aux | grep ruby
$ kill <ruby-process-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simples way to do that:

```
kill #{Process.pid}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a simple repeatable way, there's a few methods.

1. Record the PID as you start your Sinatra server, e.g.

   ```
   # Run the Sinatra server and send it to background (using &)
   ruby my_sinatra_server.rb &

   # Record the PID of the last background process (using $!)
   MY_SINATRA_SERVER_PID=$!

   # Now go ahead and do your stuff...

   # When finished, kill the sinatra server (from the same shell)
   kill $MY_SINATRA_SERVER_PID
   ```
2. Instead of using an env variable (`$MY_SINATRA_SERVER`) you can use a temporary file e.g. `my_sinatra_server.pid`

   ```
   # Run the Sinatra server and send it to background (using &)
   ruby my_sinatra_server.rb &

   # Record the PID of the last background process (using $!)
   echo $! > my_sinatra_server.pid

   # Now go ahead and do your stuff...

   # When finished, kill the sinatra server (from the same shell)
   kill $(< my_sinatra_server.pid)
   ```